# Advanced UI controls with Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Suppose:

1. A big organization needs to write a big web application with advanced UI controls, like hierarchical grid/tree and charts in addition to the regular UI controls.
2. All of these controls should preferably come from the same vendor or build on the same foundation in order to avoid integration pains.

Some may immediately advise ExtJS and they may be right ... or wrong. I do not know, because this question is about Angular 2 - what does it take to adopt it in a big enterprise that does not want to spend time developing its own framework on top of Angular 2, but start writing their application right away?

Angular 2 by itself does not ship with UI controls. Angular 2 Material does not count, because it does not have the advanced UI controls I have mentioned. So, what are the options here?

I realize that RC5 has just been released and hence it is unfair to expect any vendor to adopt it just yet. (And who knows how many RCs are to follow until it is released finally?)

However, http://www.telerik.com/blogs/kendo-ui-for-angular-2-r3-roadmap promises the first beta of Kendo UI for Angular 2 RC3 in September. Assuming a few more months to polish it and upgrade to RC5 - and we get the end of the year. So, one option which seems to become available at the end of the year is Kendo UI.

Anything else?

P.S.

It is OK to offer commercial solutions, I would not have used the term "big company" otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Eco system builds over time, not enough time at this point.

Angular 2 is different from 1, in most cases it will play nice with 3rd party components, this is mainly due to the new change detection system that does not require calling $digest/$apply but uses the concept of Zones to handle change detection which, most of the times, works out of the box.

However, angular 2 is heavily based on metadata, this means it must know as much as possible about your component, this is done by parsing the template, using decorators (@Input...) and more.

Wrapping a component requires you to understand angular 2 and the component you are wrapping in detail. You need to know what inputs and outputs to use, how to transform some callback to RxJS, how to play nicely with view encapsulation and sometimes how to manage change detection manually, where NgZone fails.

It requires good understanding in Angular 2 and some time, depending on your angular 2 skill and how well you know the components you wrap.

I would avoid wrapping...

Currently Kendo is a fair bet, Telerik are heavily involved in angular 2 through NativeScript so I expect their product integration with angular 2 to be top notch.

You can also check out Wijmo which have a nice product (http://wijmo.com/angular2/), not sure about release dates for RC5/Final.

PrimeNG (http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/) is also Angular 2 ready, not sure if they are in par with Kendo, but take a look.

You should take into consideration some factors...
* Does you'r team knows one framework better then the other? major factor here.
* Is the angular 2 components are wrapper or native angular implementations?

PrimeNG started with wrappers but the are in the process converting to native, the others I don't know.

In general, native angular implementation should be slightly better and produce a smaller footprint, however it will take some time for them to be stable.

Good luck!

Comment: PrimeNG is mostly native actually, only 7 components are wrappers as of beta13. More information is documented at their website. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup PrimeNG itself is free and open source, PrimeNG PRO is a commercial support service for companies. There are also commercial themes like material.